# creating a class based on NSMutableArray causes Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to create a class based on `NSMutableArray` filled with objects based on fictional stock market holdings, which works if I simply create an `NSMutableArray`.

```
NSMutableArray *portfolio = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: ABC, DEF, GHI, JKL, nil];
```

Once I create a class called `Portfolio` based on `NSMutableArray` and change the references to `NSMutableArray` to `Portfolio`:

```
Portfolio *portfolio = [Portfolio arrayWithObjects: ABC, DEF, GHI, JKL, nil];
```

XCode throws a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error.  I have been unable to think through what is causing the error since the `Portfolio` class is a subclass of `NSMutableArray`, and if I do nothing but create the new class it essentially is `NSMutableArray` by another name with no additional methods or attributes.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're not using ARC, right?

Comment: Why does your `Portfolio` class extend `NSMutableArray`? This is bad design. Your Portfolio class should use a mutable array, not extend it.

Comment: If you have a crash, post the backtrace (and any related error messages).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I second what everyone else has said so far: subclassing `NSMutableArray` is not the best approach. A much better approach is to create an object called `Portfolio` that is a subclass of `NSObject`, and then include an instance variable of `NSMutableArray` in it. This is called creating a *composite* object.

That being said, if you *must* subclass `NSMutableArray`, there are five primitive methods you  have to override. These are:

```
insertObject:atIndex:
removeObjectAtIndex:
addObject:
removeLastObject
replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:
```

But, it bears repeating: This is not the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

`NSMutableArray` isn't a true class that you can subclass. It's actually part of a class cluster which makes it effectively abstract. You can create a subclass of a class cluster class, but there are several things you need to do. It's much easier to create your class as a wrapper around an `NSMutableArray` instance and provide the appropriate methods explicitly.

Comment: `NSMutableArray` is actually pretty easy to subclass.  However, there is basically no reason to ever subclass it and, as you say, it is far better to wrap an object around an instance of `NSMutableArray`.